# Open Source Software: declaration of affiliation needed?

Tags: discussion, answers, spam

I know they can't profit from it monetarily, but should people who are involved in the project declare their affiliation to make their bias obvious?

[List of SharePoint development tools](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/81/what-tools-are-essential-for-every-sharepoint-2007-wss-3-0-developer/16530#16530)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is also mentioned in our [FAQ](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion)

Comment: Good call, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, full disclosure is required, even for open source. See also:

- [Is it ethical for a programmer to promote his/her own library?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/51643/18088) (my question!)
- [Using SO / SF / SU to promote your products?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10174/146095)